# Ros fuerte isn´t available on Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,  I previously installed ROS fuerte onto ubuntu 12 and 10.04 with out problems. Now, I have this trouble installing ros fuerte onto ubuntu 11.10 oneiric. I have test with 2 different computers and I have tried full, desktop and base installation. any sugestions?

```
Package ros-fuerte-ros-comm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ros-fuerte-ros-comm' has no installation candidate
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46206/ros-fuerte-isn%C2%B4t-available-on-ubuntu-11.10-oneiric./) by [LeonardoLeottau](https://answers.ros.org/users/3140/leonardoleottau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-18**:
What's the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`?

**Comment by [LeonardoLeottau](https://answers.ros.org/users/3140/leonardoleottau/) on 2012-10-19**:
Hi:
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu oneiric main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Repository resynced.  Oneiric 32 should be available again.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. It seems like the debians are really missing for Oneiric i386 (64bit seems to be available btw.). I hope Willow can resolve that soon. As a temporary solution, you can use the shadow-fixed repository instead of the normal debian repository. Just replace the content of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list with the following:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu oneiric main
```

Note that the repository contains the debian packages that go into the next official update. There is a certain chance that updates break so you should switch back to the actual repository as soon as it contains the packages again.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2